# Obtener informacion en base a selección de DropDownList en ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente código para realizar el registro de un presupuesto, pero tengo ahora un inconveniente en el cual, dependiendo de mi selección debe visualizarme el tipo de pieza dental.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi metodo GetPieza que dependiendo de la selección del tipo de dentadura debería visualizar uno u otro resultado

```
  public List<SelectListItem> GetPieza(ApplicationDbContext context, String tmp)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = null;
        try
        {
            selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            if (tmp.Equals("DENTADURA TEMPORAL"))
                context.TBL_PIEZA.Where(pie => pie.PIE_DENT.Equals("TEMPORAL")).OrderBy(pie => pie.PIE_ID).ToList().ForEach(item =>
                {
                    selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = item.PIE_ID.ToString(),
                        Text = item.PIE_PIEZA
                    });
                });
            else if (tmp.Equals("DENTADURA ADULTA"))
                context.TBL_PIEZA.Where(pie => pie.PIE_DENT.Equals("ADULTA")).OrderBy(pie => pie.PIE_ID).ToList().ForEach(item =>
                {
                    selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = item.PIE_ID.ToString(),
                        Text = item.PIE_PIEZA
                    });
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: '{ex}'");
        }
        return selectListItems;

    }
```

Mi Page Reg_Presup en donde hago la llamada dependiendo del resultado escogido en el COMBO tipo de dentadura en el metodo OnGET.

```
PRE_COD = TempCodPre,
                Odontologo_Lista = _lOdontologo.GetOdontologo(_context),
                Dentadura_Lista = _lDentadura.GetDentadura(_context),
                Pieza_Lista = _lPieza.GetPieza(_context, Convert.ToString(_lDentadura.GetDentadura(_context))), -- AQUI ESTA EL ERROR Y NO CARGA CORRECTAMENTE, CREERIA YO QUE ESTARIA OBTENIENDO MAL LA INFORMACION ALMACENADA EN ESE CAMPO.
                Tratamiento_Lista = _lTratamiento.GetTratamiento(_context)
```

Mi Page Reg_Presup

```
   <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                {
                                                <label>Tipo Dentadura:</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Dentadura_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                 new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                            <label>Tipo Dentadura:</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Dentadura_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
         "ESCOGA UN TIPO DE DENTADURA", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                }
                                                <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                {
                                                    <label>Tipo Pieza Dental:</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Pieza_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                 new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                            <label>Tipo Pieza Dental:</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Pieza_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
         "ESCOGA UNA PIEZA DENTAL", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                }
                                                <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Con esta función en mi en mi `DropDownList` obtengo la informacion escogida en tipo dentadura para posteriormente enviar el dato en un query para que se llene automáticamente el siguiente

```
   @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Dentadura_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
         "ESCOGA UN TIPO DE DENTADURA", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "SeleccionDentadura()" })
```

Función en jquery

```
    function SeleccionDentadura() {
    var selectedVal = document.getElementById("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").value;
    console.log(selectedVal)
};
```

Agradezco su colaboración y ayuda para saber que estoy errando en mi código.

Comment: Y cual es el problema, donde esta el error, en jquery, en c#, en donde?

Comment: Al seleccionar el combo tipo dentadura mediante `Jquery` obtengo el valor seleccionado, el problema reside es que ese valor como puedo realizar para que envié el dato obtenido a través de el método a este metodo  `Pieza_Lista = _lPieza.GetPieza(_context, Convert.ToString(_lDentadura.GetDentadura(_context)))` para poder obtener la nueva lista que dependerá en base a la selección

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola yo tenia un problema similar pero en asp.net mvc espero te pueda servir mi respuesta y si infringí alguna regla espero algún otro miembro o moderador me lo haga saber

yo mande ambas listas relacionadas desde mi controlador equipo estas eran

Marca equipo
Tipo equipo

vista

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Tipo de Equipo</label>

        @Html.DropDownList("Eq_tblTipoEquipos", (SelectList)ViewBag.Eq_tblTipoEquipos_id, "Seleccion uno", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select NombreTipo", @required = "required" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Marca y modelo</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id", null, "Seleccion uno", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select ", @required = "required" })
    </div>
```

aqui estoy utilizando chosen-select

en mi js la funcion seria la siguiente

```
$("#Eq_tblTipoEquipos").change(function () {
    var tipo = $("#Eq_tblTipoEquipos").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/GetEquipo",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: tipo },
        success: function (d) {
            $("#Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id").html(d);
            $("#Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id").trigger("chosen:updated");
        }
    })
});
```

Aparte me cree una clase que llame GetDataSelectController la cual me traera el filtrado

```
public class GetDataSelectController : Controller
{
    private MIDATABASE db = new MIDATABASE ();

    [Route("~/GetEquipo")]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetEquipo(int id)
    {

        var equipo = db.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos.Where(a => a.Eq_tblTipoEquipos_id == id);
        string html = "'HTML':'";
        foreach (var tipo in equipo)
        {
            html += "<option value=\"" + tipo.id + "\">" + tipo.Marca + " - " + tipo.Modelo + "</option>";
        }
        html += "'";
        return Json(html);
    }

}
```

Como mencione este ejemplo lo hice en Asp.net mvc con EF no eh tenido el gusto de usar asp.net core pero pienso que tal vez te puede servir como guía o inspiración para darte una idea, en lo que encuentras la respuesta adecuada

Reitero si mi respuesta es inadecuada espero me lo hagan saber gracias

Comment: Tu idea esta muy bien planteada, pero deberías apegarte a la tecnología que se esta usando en la pregunta... Esto con el fin de que tu pregunta sea mas clara y concisa.

Comment: Hola TheOligarch tratare de hacer la modificación apuntando a .Net Core será un poco mas tarde para hacer el mejor planteamiento posible de igual manera si alguien puede tomar mi ejemplo y adaptarlo a la tecnología solicitada es mas que bienvenido

Comment: Al aplicar el codigo del html.dropdownlist me aparece el siguiente `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN'.` que podria ser?

Answer (score 0):

Al final siguiendo las indicaciones de tu código , lo use y finalmente quedo así mi código jquery.

```
 function SeleccionDentadura() {
    var selectedVal = document.getElementById("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").value;
    if (selectedVal == "DENTADURA TEMPORAL") {
        selectedVal = "TEMPORAL"
    }
    else if (selectedVal == "DENTADURA ADULTA") {
        selectedVal = "ADULTA"
    }
    //alert(selectedVal);
    console.log(selectedVal)
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Presupuesto/Get_Pieza_Lista",
            data: { 'PIE_DENT': selectedVal },
            success:
                function (resul) {
                    //  resul = JSON.stringify(resul);
                    // VACIAMOS EL DropDownList
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").empty();
                    //AÑADIMOS UN NUEVO label CON EL NOMBRE DEL ELEMENTO SELECCIONADO
                    var mOptions = `<option value="">ESCOGA UNA PIEZA DENTAL ${$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN option:selected").text()}</option>`;
                    // CONSTRUIMOS EL DropDownList A PARTIR DEL RESULTADO Json(data)
                    console.log(resul)
                    $.each(resul, function (index, row) {
                        mOptions += `<option value="${row.piE_ID}">${row.piE_PIEZA}</option>`;
                    });
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").append(mOptions)
                    console.log(mOptions)
                }, error:
                function (e) {
                    alert("ERROR: " + e.message);
                }
        });
};
```